# How to not escape a character in a Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm, sql-like, contains

I use Django, ORM.

I don't want the character '%' to be escaped.

```
name=''
author=''
annotation = 'harry%magic%school'

criterion_name = Q(name__contains=cleaned_data['name'])
criterion_author = Q(author__contains=cleaned_data['author'])
criterion_annotation = Q(annotation__contains=cleaned_data['annotation'])

Book.objects.filter(criterion_name, criterion_author, criterion_annotation)
```

I get `'%harry\%magic\%school%'`:

```
select name, author, annotation from books 
where name LIKE '%%' AND 
author LIKE '%%' AND 
annotation LIKE '%harry\%magic\%school%'
```

I want to get `'%harry%magic%school%'`:

```
select name, author, annotation from books 
where name LIKE '%%' AND 
author LIKE '%%' AND 
annotation LIKE '%harry%magic%school%'
```

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [`docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements) it will escape automatically both `%` and `_`, there is no option to not escape it by using built-in lookups.

So, you could use [`.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to write a raw `SQL` which is undesirable in most cases, even for the most complex ones. Or, write a [custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-lookups/#how-to-write-custom-lookups):

lookups.py

```py
class Like(models.Lookup):
    lookup_name = "like"

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "%s LIKE %s" % (lhs, rhs), params


models.CharField.register_lookup(Like)
```

views.py

```py
from .lookups import Like

def some_view(request):
    name = ''
    author = ''
    annotation = '%harry%magic%school%'

    books = Book.objects.filter(
        Q(name__contains=name), 
        Q(author__contains=author), 
        Q(annotation__like=annotation)
    )
    print(books.query)
    return render(request, 'blank.html')
```

Which yields the following query (the output of `print`):

```
SELECT "myapp_book"."id", "myapp_book"."name", "myapp_book"."author", "myapp_book"."annotation" 
FROM "myapp_book" 
WHERE (
    "myapp_book"."name" LIKE %% ESCAPE '\' 
    AND "myapp_book"."author" LIKE %% ESCAPE '\' 
    AND "myapp_book"."annotation" LIKE %harry%magic%school%
)
```

**Obs:** All your criteria are against the `name` field, so I just assumed it was wrong and changed it for each variable to match its respective field.